# Unstable Wifi Intel 7265

Tags: networking, drivers, 17.04, intel-wireless, iwlwifi

since upgrading to Ubuntu 17.04 I noticed unstable Wifi Connections (the connection drops randomly on 2,4Ghz and 5 Ghz Networks). I tried upgrading the [iwlwifi drivers](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git), but unfortunately this didn't help.

My Network Card is a Intel 7265:

```
Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095b] (rev 99)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:5210]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

For some reasons Ubuntu seems to load `iwflwifi-7265D-26`

```
modinfo iwlwifi | grep 7265
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-26.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode
```

which is not present:

```
sudo dmesg -T | grep iwl
iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-26.ucode failed with error -2
iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-25.ucode failed with error -2
iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-24.ucode failed with error -2
iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-23.ucode failed with error -2
iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 22.391740.0 op_mode iwlmvm
iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: renamed from wlan0
iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
...
```

In my `/lib/firmware` folder I have this firmware files:

```
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265-10.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265-12.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265-16.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265-8.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265-9.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265D-12.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265D-16.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265D-17.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265D-21.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265D-22.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
```

Which firmware do I have to load? What is the difference between `7265` and `7265D` firmware (I guess 2,4/5Ghz?). Why does Ubuntu not use the most recent firmware (7265D-29)?

Thanks!

P.S.: I tried to set the BSSID to the 2,4Ghz&5Ghz Network, this didn't solve the problem.

Comment: I have a very similar problem on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS ... https://askubuntu.com/questions/1078266/unstable-network-connection?noredirect=1#comment1771080_1078266